# Tutorial in creating DHTMLX JavaPlanner for netbeans

Tags: java, dhtmlx

I'm new in creating web application in java and I'm planning to use javaplanner but the tutorials in creating javaplanner are only for eclipse which looks different in netbeans.. Can someone provide me a useful tutorial in making javaplanner for netbeans?